# Passing value to other activity with custom array adapter

Tags: android-arrayadapter, textview, android-seekbar, android

may I ask how to pass the value to other `Activity` using the code below? This is because I want to pass each value of `TextView` in my ListView to another `Activity`. Thank you.

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);

        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    /**
     * Here we go and get our rowlayout.xml file and set the textview text.
     * This happens for every row in your listview.
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.criteriaName);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtView2);
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.sbBar);

        // Setting the text to display
        textView.setText(values.get(position));

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                textView2.setText(""+i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

So, how am I going to pass the value in `TextView2` to another `Activity`?

Comment: I think sending an Intent on triggering of listener is the normal way, if that is what you mean by 'passing to another activity'.

Comment: Hi, how am I going to get the value of each seek bar? Since I may have different value for each seek bar based on the sliding, I want to pass the value to another activity to do the calculation. Thank you.

Comment: All methods in listener have a reference to current seek bar after change. I would go from there. Computations can be done before intent messaging.

Comment: Can't you just do your calculation onProgressChanged and maybe add textview values to some array then add array or do each calculation first then get value to array and then go to the next activity

Answer (score 0):

At first convert you Textview to a String then , do this

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,ClassOfNextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("My_String",convertedString);

startActivity(i);
```

On the next Activty you have to do this, to get your String from your first Activity.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String newString = (String) i.getSerializableExtra(My_String):
```